# Seg fault when saving data using boost::serialization

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault, boost-serialization

When trying to save the database using boost serialization, I encounter the segfault that I could not resolve.  Would you please help?  Any suggestion is greately appreciated.
I've pinned down the statement below as the culprit but not sure of how to resolve it

```
oa << *this;
```

My code section is below:

```
template<class Archive>
void nDB::serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
    ar & _LAYERS;
    ar & _MACROS;
    ar & _MODULES;
    ar & _INSTS;
}

void nDB::save_db(string filename) {
    std::ofstream ofs(filename.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    //assert(ofs.good());
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << *this;
    ofs.close();
}
```

Hi, 
I was able to pin point the issue to a circular reference in my database.  The code are below:

```
    template<class Archive>
    void pin::serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
    ar & pin_Port;
    ar & pin_Layer;
    }
```

and

```
    template<class Archive>
    void port::serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version){
    ar & port_Name;
    ar & port_Use;
    ar & port_Dir;
    ar & port_PINS;
    }
```

Hi below are my class definition

```
    class pin {
    public:
    port*       pin_Port;
    layer*      pin_Layer;
    // rect*       pin_shape;

    pin();
    ~pin();

    void         set_port(port*);
    void         set_layer(layer*);
    string       get_name();
    port*        get_port();
    layer*       get_layer();
    string       get_layer_name();
    double       get_layer_width();
    private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version);
    };
    class port {
    public:
    string     port_Name;
    char       port_Use;
    char       port_Dir;
    pin_vector port_PINS;
    port();
    ~port();

    void         set_name(string);
    void         set_use(int);
    void         set_dir(int);
    string       get_name(void);
    string       get_use(void);
    string       get_dir(void);
    void         add_pin(pin*);
    pin_vector   get_all_pins(void);

    private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the culprit is `ofs.close();`. The `binary_oarchive` object needs to go out of scope *before* the underlying stream is closed, because the `binary_oarchive` object tries to write remaining data and flush the stream in its destructor.

Standard streams are flushed and closed automatically when they go out of scope, so the line is completely unnecessary (and in this case, harmful). Remove it and you should be good to go.

(Unrelated, but `_LAYERS`, `_MACROS`, etc. are **terrible** names, and in fact are illegal in user code. Get rid of either the leading underscore or the capital letters, preferably both.)

Comment: Hi ildjarn, I've done what you suggested but it doesn't solve it.  Do you see anything else that is wrong with the code?  Thanks ildjarn

Comment: @Binh : No, you haven't shown enough code to be able to tell. ;-] For the code that's shown presently, just removing `ofs.close();` puts it in a good state, so your problem must be in code that you haven't shown.

Comment: Thanks ildjarn, you are absolutely right. I was able to deduct the issue to a circular reference in my database. What I did for debugging was sequentially turning off each component in the serialize function for each class. At the end I was able to identify that it comes from a circular reference. Now I guess my question will be condensed to how to make boost serialization taking care of circular reference or it won't be possible at all. My code for the circular reference is below:

Comment: Oops, do you know how to add code in the comment section?  Thanks ildjarn,

Comment: @Binh : Best to edit it into your question, so it can be formatted properly.

Comment: Oh OK, thank ildjarn.  I'll add them into my comment.  Would you please take a look at it and show me if I can serialize them circular reference?  Thank you so much ildjarn

Comment: @Binh : You'll need to show your full class definitions for `pin` and `port`, especially the declaration of `pin::pin_Port` and `port::port_PINS`.

Comment: Hi ildjarn, I just did.  Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I got the feeling that the order of serialization has something to do with this.

Comment: Assuming `pin_vector` is a typedef for `std::vector<pin*>`, the `serialize` member functions you've shown should be fine as long as some `pin::pin_Port` is eventually null or some `port::port_PINS` is eventually empty. If some `pin` object's `pin::pin_Port` points to a `port` object that contains the original `pin` object inside of `port::port_PINS` then you indeed do have an infinite recursion problem and will have to rethink your design.

Comment: Hi ildjarn, I need to have pin::pin_Port as I design my database so that my user can access these object independently.  So you meant boost serialization can't handle circular reference?  But I was able to do this like yesterday.  I was adding some more classes and methods and unintendedly change the original structure.  That's the reason I believe that the serialization order is the cause.  I don't understand the reason though.

Comment: @Binh : Sorry, I don't know if/how Boost.Serialization handles circular references. Personally, I would try to eliminate them during serialization just to see if that fixes the issue, then go from there.

Comment: I think I will give it another 2 hours.  If I can't solve it, then I guess I have to follow your suggestion.  Anyway, thank you so much for your help.  I really appreciate it.