# boost serialization segmentation fault

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have been trying to serialize some object using `boost::serialization`. 
Look at the below code:

```
class Pedestal
{
    typedef std::vector<double> DataVector;

public:
    /** irrelevant functions */

private:

    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const
    {
        if(version >0){
            ar & m_normalization;
            ar & m_isNormalized;
            ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_pedestals);
        }
    }

    int m_normalization;
    bool m_isNormalized;
    DataVector m_pedestals;
```

And the other function, that is trying to save pedestal into file.

```
void PedestalCalculator::savePedestalToFile(const std::string& p_filename)
{

    {
        ofstream l_file(p_filename);
        boost::archive::text_oarchive l_textArchive(l_file);
        l_textArchive & m_pedestal;
    }

}
```

The output of gdb:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> 0x00007fffde47397f in boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::save_object(void const*, boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer const&) () from /usr/lib64/libboost_serialization.so.5
>
> Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install boost-serialization-1.41.0-25.el6.x86_64 freetype-2.3.11-14.el6_3.1.x86_64 glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 keyutils-libs-1.4-5.el6.x86_64 krb5-libs-1.10.3-33.el6.x86_64 libcom_err-1.41.12-21.el6.x86_64 libselinux-2.0.94-5.8.el6.x86_64 ncurses-libs-5.7-3.20090208.el6.x86_64 nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-18.el6_6.x86_64 openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 readline-6.0-4.el6.x86_64 snoopy-1.7.10-1.el6.x86_64 sssd-client-1.11.6-30.el6_6.3.x86_64 zlib-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64
>
> (gdb) bt
>
> #0  0x00007fffde47397f in boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::save_object(void const*, boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer const&) () from /usr/lib64/libboost_serialization.so.5
>
> #1  0x00007fffde7266d3 in TbUT::PedestalCalculator::savePedestalToFile(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&) ()
>
> from /afs/cern.ch/user/a/adendek/cmtuser/Kepler_v2r1/InstallArea/x86_64-slc6-gcc48-opt/lib/libTbUT.so

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? I spent a lot of time reading manuals and debugging and I cannot find  solution.

Comment: The method normalizePedestal() is irrelevant. I find that problem is caused by the line:
   l_textArchive & m_pedestal;
After commented it program works (no segfault).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038090/seg-fault-when-saving-data-using-boostserialization) is easily found when you put your question title into Google. Is this the problem? If not, please explain (editing your question) why. This will help people who will try to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @BartoszKP 99.9% says that's the dupe

Comment: I think the this post doesn't contain solution for my problem. I edited a little bit my code. Can you help my with my issue?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue with the code you've provided - I've successfully serialized an instance of your class with exactly the same 5 lines you have in your `savePedestalToFile` function. You need to construct a minimal, compilable example that crashes.

Comment: Thank you Bartosz for verification.